# I have error in mysql function? ERROR is Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, function

I have error in mysql function. I attached my code below here.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CheckAccount6(ids INT)
RETURNS integer
BEGIN

DECLARE opening INT;
DECLARE a INT;

SET a = 0;

select q.invoice, q.timestamp, 
(select sum(o.totprice) from sp_orderdetails o where o.quotation_no = q.id) as amount
from sp_quotation q where q.cid = ids and q.invoice != '0'

UNION

select 0, t.timestamp, t.amount from sp_transactions t where t.cid = ids and t.status like 'Approved';

IF(invoice = 0) THEN
 a = a - amount;
ELSE
 a = a + amount;

return a;
END $$
```

Comment: You can't use a `SELECT` statement in a function unless you use `INTO` to store the results in variables.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Why are you selecting all those other fields if you only care about `invoice` and `amount`? And what do you expect those variables to contain if the query returns more than one row?

Comment: After selecting those variables want to write some looping conditions

Comment: You need to use a cursor to loop over the results of a query.

Comment: But why don't you just use `SUM()` in the query instead of a loop?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: i need to loop query and return sum(amount) with from and to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a `SELECT` query in a function or procedure without assigning the result to a variable, it tries to return it. This is allowed for procedures, because they can be used as a query, and the result of the `SELECT` query becomes the result of `CALL procedurename`.

But a function can just return a single value, not a query result set. If you use a query in the function, it has to store the results in variables and then use those to compute the function's return value. If you need to process all the rows of a result set, it needs to use a cursor.

Since you just want to return a sum, you can use `SUM()` in the query, and return that. There's no need for any variables or looping.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CheckAccount6(ids INT)
RETURNS integer
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(o.totprice)
            FROM sp_orderdetails AS o
            JOIN sp_quotation AS q ON o.quotation_no = q.id
            WHERE q.cid = ids AND q.invoice != '0')
           -
           (SELECT SUM(t.amount)
            FROM sp_transactions t
            WHERE t.cid = ids and t.status like 'Approved');
END $$
```